# React Admin: I'd like to route to <Show> view from a list

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-admin

I'm currently using [react admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/).
I would like to route to my `ActivityShow` component when I click a row in the Resource list.

When I click the row, the app routes to `http://localhost:3000/#/activity/music_lesson/1` which is the empty route. It doesn't show my item detail.

My `ActivityShow` component is actually rendered at this route: `http://localhost:3000/#/activity/music_lesson/1/show` by default.

Do I have to create custom react route?
Or is there any other options for that?

Here is my `App.js` file

```js
// in src/App.js
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource, ListGuesser } from 'react-admin';
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';
import {ActivityList} from './components/activity';
import {ActivityCreate} from './components/activity'
import DataProvider from './dataProvider/dataProvider'
import {ActivityShow} from './components/activity';

    const App = () => (
          <Admin dataProvider={DataProvider}>
               <Resource 
               name="activity/music_lesson" 
               options={{ label: 'Music Lesson' }} 
               list={ActivityList} 
               create={ActivityCreate}
               show={ActivityShow}
          />
              <Resource 
              name="activity/art_theraphy" 
              options={{ label: 'Art Theraphy' }} 
              list={ActivityList}
              create={ActivityCreate}
              show={ActivityShow}
               />
              <Resource 
              name="activity/relaxing_music" 
              options={{ label: 'Relaxing Music' }} 
              list={ActivityList} 
              create={ActivityCreate}
              show={ActivityShow}
              />
              <Resource 
              name="activity/stayfit_video" 
              options={{ label: 'Stayfit Video' }} 
              list={ActivityList}
              create={ActivityCreate}
              show={ActivityShow}
              />
          </Admin>
    );

    export default App;
```

Comment: Interesting!! Since you have no `edit`, what are you are passing to the `rowClick` prop within your `List/Datagrid`?

Answer (score 1):

In my own code I ran into this situation, and figured out you can add the `link` prop with a value `show` to direct to the show route.

```
<ReferenceField source="id" reference="accounts" link="show">
    <TextField source="name"/>
</ReferenceField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `import {ActivityList} from './components/activity';` you will have something similar to the following:

```
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";
import { List, Datagrid, TextField, NumberField } from 'react-admin';
import { ActivityListProps } from "./ActivityList.interface";


const ActivityList = (props: ActivityListProps): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <List {...props}>
        {/* change the rowClick from edit -> show */}
        <Datagrid rowClick="show">
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="description" />
            <TextField source="name" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
};

export default ActivityList;
```

Simply change the `<DataGrid rowClick="edit">` to `<DataGrid rowClick="show">`.